# Nodejs-Mysql query get results after webpage is loaded, which gives undefined error

Tags: mysql, node.js, callback

I want to display some data(all Menus) in homepage either user is logged in or not.
I am getting that data whenever logged-in status is checked.

- It works fine if user is logged in,
- but if user is not logged in it throws error as it says 'undefined'.

I did some console.log to find what is happening.
It gets the data after webpage is loaded which results in error.

**Controller Code:**

```
exports.isLogedIn = async (req, res, next) => {
 db.query("SELECT * FROM menu", (err, result) => {
   if (!result) {
     return next();
   }
   console.log(result); // Logs when webpage is loaded.
   req.menus = result;
 });

// req.message = "Inside middleware";
// console.log(req.cookies);
if (req.cookies.jwt) {
try {
  // verify the token
  const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(
    req.cookies.jwt,
    process.env.JWT_SECRET
  );

  var sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = ?";
  if (decoded.userType !== "customer")
    sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE id = ?";

  // Check if the user still exist
  //   console.log(decoded);
  db.query(sqlQuery, [decoded.id], (err, result) => {
    // console.log(result);
    if (!result) {
      return next();
    }
    req.user = result[0];
    return next();
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  return next();
}
} else {
next();
}};
```

**Route Code:**

```
router.get("/", commonController.isLogedIn, (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.user);
   console.log(req.menus);

  res.render("index", {
     user: req.user,
     menus: req.menus,
  });
});
```

**Error:**

```
       72|
       73|     <div class="container row justify-content-center centerpage">
    >> 74|       <% menus.forEach(element => { %>
       75|
       76|       <div class="card col-sm-4" style="width: 18rem">
       77|         <img

    Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
         at eval (eval at compile (~\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:661:12), 
    <anonymous>:37:14)
       at index (~\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:691:17)
       at tryHandleCache (~\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
       at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (~\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
       at View.render (~\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
       at tryRender (~\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
       at Function.render (~\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
       at ServerResponse.render (~\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
       at ~\routes\pages.js:16:7
       at Layer.handle [as handle_request]               
    ~\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

I am very new to nodejs, wasted my 3-4 hours studying different things but nothing worked for me. I know some similar threads are available but i am not able to fix. It would be great if i get answers related to my circumstances.

Comment: Where is the error message?

Comment: Error is: "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined".

Comment: Actually I was hoping that you copy and paste the error message [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64202862/edit).. especially the lines where it mention the js file name and line numbers where the error occurred.

Comment: I have added the error which i receive hope it helps.